# buildroot external cmake package makefile fails install

Tags: buildroot

I am trying to install my external package, which is built fine by the cross-compile toolchain but fails on the install step with the error

```
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Release"
-- Installing: /home/username/Projects/ProjectName/ProjectName_software/ProjectName_OS/build_ProjectName_os_raspberrypi3/target/home/username/Projects/ProjectName/ProjectName_software/ProjectName_
OS/build_ProjectName_os_raspberrypi3/build/APPNAME/APPNAME
APPNAME: installs files in /home/userName/Projects/ProjectName/ProjectName_software/ProjectName_OS/build_ProjectName_os_raspberrypi3/target//home/username/Projects/ProjectName/ProjectName
_software/ProjectName_OS/build_ProjectName_os_raspberrypi3
package/pkg-generic.mk:315: recipe for target '/home/alex/Projects/BlackBox/bbefx_software/BBEFX_OS/build_bbefx_os_raspberrypi3/build/BBEFX_CORE/.stamp_
target_installed' failed
```

I am guessing that the path prefixed by --Installing is the one generated by the package makefile and the one prefixed by APPNAME is the one that buildroot is expecting APPNAME to install to. Hence why the .stamp_target_install fails

The obvious issue is that the path buildroot expects is

```
/target//home/username/
```

This isn't the path that I would like to install to (usr/bin would be preferable). However I can't see how to specify a path within the package make file, which is as follows:

```
APPNAME_SITE = $(TOPDIR)/../../APPNAME
APPNAME_SITE_METHOD = local
APPNAME_INSTALL_TARGET = YES

$(eval $(cmake-package))
```

With the CMakeLists.txt being:

```
#
# CMake options
#

# CMake version
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.0 FATAL_ERROR)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)

option(BUILD_DOC "Create and install the HTML based API documentation (requires Doxygen)" ${DOXYGEN_FOUND})

# project name
project(APPNAME)


IF(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
  MESSAGE(STATUS "No build type selected, default to Release")
  SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release")
ENDIF()
STRING(TOUPPER "${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}" uppercase_CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
IF(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE AND
    NOT uppercase_CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES "^(DEBUG|RELEASE)$")
  MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "Invalid value for CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE: ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}")
ENDIF()

if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")
  add_definitions(-DDEBUG)
endif()

if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -std=c++14")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -Wall -std=c++14")

endif()

if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "GNU")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -std=c++14")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -w -std=c++14")

endif()

# enable c++
enable_language(C CXX)

# project version
set(VERSION_MAJOR 0)
set(VERSION_MINOR 1)
set(VERSION_PATCH 0)

# Find all sources and headers in the source folder
file(GLOB_RECURSE APPNAME_SOURCES "source/*.cpp")
file(GLOB_RECURSE APPNAME_HEADERS "source/*.hpp" "source/*.h")

# Add header directories, remove dupes
set (APPNAME_INCLUDE_DIRS "")
foreach (_headerFile ${APPNAME_HEADERS})
    get_filename_component(_dir ${_headerFile} PATH)
    list (APPEND APPNAME_INCLUDE_DIRS ${_dir})
endforeach()
list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES APPNAME_INCLUDE_DIRS)

# Add sources and headers to exec
add_executable (APPNAME ${APPNAME_SOURCES})
target_include_directories(APPNAME PRIVATE ${APPNAME_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Add Libs to link
 find_package(libconfigpp REQUIRED)
 find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system log REQUIRED)
 include_directories(${LIBCONFIGPP_INCLUDE_DIR} $Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS)
 target_link_libraries(APPNAME ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${LIBCONFIGPP_LIBRARIES})
 add_definitions(-DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK)


# Add platform specific Libs and preproc macros
if(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} STREQUAL "Linux")
    add_definitions(-DSYSTEM_LINUX)
    add_definitions(-D__UNIX_JACK__ )
    find_package(libjack REQUIRED)
    target_link_libraries(APPNAME ${JACK_LIBRARIES})
    set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
    find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
    target_link_libraries(APPNAME Threads::Threads)
endif()
if(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} STREQUAL "Darwin")
    add_definitions(-DSYSTEM_DARWIN)
    add_definitions(-D__MACOSX_CORE__)
    find_library(COREMIDI_LIBRARY CoreMIDI)
    find_library(COREFOUNDATION_LIBRARY CoreFoundation)
    find_library(COREAUDIO_LIBRARY CoreAudio)
    target_link_libraries(APPNAME ${COREFOUNDATION_LIBRARY} ${COREMIDI_LIBRARY} ${COREAUDIO_LIBRARY})
endif()

set(CONFIGFILE source/APPNAME_CONFIG.cfg)

#file(COPY ${CONFIGFILE} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
install (TARGETS APPNAME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

#
# Build Documentation
#

find_package(Doxygen)
if(BUILD_DOC)
    if(NOT DOXYGEN_FOUND)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Doxygen is needed to build the documentation.")
    endif()

    set(DOXYFILE_IN ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/source/doc/Doxyfile.in)
    set(DOXYFILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Doxyfile)
    configure_file(${DOXYFILE_IN} ${DOXYFILE} @ONLY)

    add_custom_target(DOC
        COMMAND ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} ${DOXYFILE}
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
        COMMENT "Generating API documentation with Doxygen"
        VERBATIM)

        add_custom_command(TARGET DOC
                POST_BUILD
                COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/source/doc/Documentation.html ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/doc
        )
    install(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/html DESTINATION share/doc)
endif()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

`install (TARGETS APPNAME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})`

is wrong. According to the CMake documentation, `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` is the *The path to the top level of the build tree.*, which is why your binary gets installed in the wrong place.

Please replace this line with:

`install (TARGETS APPNAME DESTINATION bin)`

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I hadn't actually tested the make install command and was simply running the binaries from the build folder when testing the program. Thanks also for all your resources on free electrons :) they're super helpful coming to buildroot as an embedded newbie.